# Is it possible to capture events of VideoPlayer in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer, observers, publisher

I want to create a `VideoPlayer` in SwiftUI, but I want to react to events like:

- user starts the video
- user stops the video
- user drags the slider

Is it possible somehow? All I found was one defualt event in `NotificationCenter`, but called `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`. I also searched here and everyone recommends to observe the `rate` property of `AVPlayer`, but that's not good for me, as I can't distinguish if the user stopped playing the video, or just drags the slider. Does anyone have a solution for this?

`VideoPlayer` is a built-in element, basically with this code it works:

```
var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(
            player: AVPlayer(
                url: URL(string: "https://vid.tasty.co/output/217191/hls24_1632510042.m3u8"
                )!
            )
        )
    }
```

Comment: You may start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480652/struggling-with-notificationcenter-combine-in-swiftui-avplayer

Comment: Thanks, I've checked that already, that's only a solution for the case when the video ends by it's own because it has finished. I could also cover that case with `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`, but still no clue how to handle the cases when the user stops it or changes the slider